# React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of > null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have the following piece of code. It is basically just a button with an event handler, and the class is supposed to hold some state wich as of now is only a counter, set to 0 initially.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import styles from './SentenceView.css';

export default class SentenceView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  getNextSentence() {
    console.log(this.state.count); // this &
    this.setState({count: 2}); // this gives me an error
    console.log("Executed");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className={styles.container}> */}
        <div>
          <h1>SentenceView</h1>
          <button onClick={this.getNextSentence}>Next Sentence</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the getNextSentence button I get:

> SentenceView.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of
>   null

I am aware that this error is not uncommon, but I have not yet found any solution on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your constructor at the bottom:

```
this.getNextSentence = this.getNextSentence.bind(this);
```

Comment: I'm surprised this worked, as I came across something similar but couldn't get it to work. It worked this time, so thank you for that! I do not quite understand what it does though. Could you (or somebody) explain to me (briefly) what exactly this does?

Comment: @GeorgeWelder you can read more from when ES6 class syntax was supported here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html. Essentially - createClass took care of autobinding - however, with class syntax you need to bind this to the method yourself (otherwise you lose reference to this when invoking the function)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the method to the class in the `constructor` function and then reference it the same way you are doing in your question in your `onClick` handler.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.getNextSentence = this.getNextSentence.bind(this);
  }
```

Alternatively, you can `bind` the function to the `SentenceView` class.

```
<button onClick={this.getNextSentence.bind(this)}>
```

However, as explained by Geoffrey Abdallah in the comment below binding in render will create a new function for every render.

Another option would be to take advantage of ES6's `arrow` functions in your `render` method.

```
<button onClick={() => this.getNextSentence()}>
```

Comment: Edited to delete comment - new edited answer shows binding in the constructor (binding in render will create a new function for every render)

Comment: Thanks @PaulFitzgerald! I'm in total agreement that the perf implications are negligible for most situations (which is why I still have some arrow functions in some of my renders.) Just wanted to throw out there what's considered 'best practice' for this kind of method binding.

Comment: @GeoffreyAbdallah again just FYI apparently (according to that article) the preferred approach is to use an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Component doesn't autobind `this` on methods like createClass does. You need to bind `this` to getNextSentence in the constructor (or you can use es7 property initializer syntax to do the binding in the class itself.) Read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html)